# Selenium: Expected conditions for explicit waiting using WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

Selenium offers explicit wait functionality to handle situations (for example) when you want to execute a `click()` operation on an element which is not yet clickable.

The syntax is as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(self._driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(BY.ID, 'some-id')).click()
```

This tells the program to wait until some element (located by its ID) is clickable.

Under the hood, `EC.element_to_be_clickable()` calls an internal `_find_element()` function reading in the parameters specified by `element_to_be_clickable()`.. In this case, it searches the DOM for elements corresponding with the ID: `some-id`.

I cant however, directly pass in a `WebElement` object into the `element_to_be_clickable()` function because it fails in the internal `_find_element()` call.

Is there a way I can use these explicit waits (or any alternatives) while working with the `WebElements` themselves?

My initial thought is I can download the code and add functionality to bypass the `_find_element()` under certain conditions but wondering if anyone else has had this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to set implicity_wait

Comment: There’s more than one way to skin a cat, generally as part of framework, we will have the the methods to click the elements, let's say `ClickElement(how,what)` or `ClickElement(what)` and with in the method we will call the EC and perform the operation. By this way I don't have to worry about the location strategy everytime calling the EC.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you can use EC with the `what`... assuming your `what` is a `WebElement` as in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @Wonka Implicit waits are not very stable. For example, suppose a wait spinner is blocking a clickable element while the website pulls data from a backend service. An implicit wait of 5 seconds might always be sufficient in overcoming this on my machine, but will completely buckle if a user tries to run the same code with a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, stretching the WebDriverWait operations a bit - by passing to it not a driver object, but the element itself, and a lambda function to the `until()`.

As you've seen in its code, the "meat" of WebDriverWait's `until()` is to call the passed function with an argument the passed object, and return the outcome:

```
value = method(self._driver)
if value:
    return value
```

So in theory, you could pass the element itself, and as a function to have an expression that returns the element if all checks are matching, or `False` if not.
The original `element_to_be_clickable` expects two things out of the element (apart from it to be present) - `is_displayed()` and `is_enabled()`. Thus the expression, inside a lambda, would be:

```
lambda x: x if x.is_displayed() and x.is_enabled() else False
```

And the whole call would he:

```
WebDriverWait(self.your_webelemt_object, 20).until(lambda x: x if x.is_displayed() and x.is_enabled() else False).click()
```

---

I said "in theory", causes I'm typing this on mobile :), and I haven't checked it in practice (but the theoery  is solid ;).  What could go wrong? An exception to be raised, that is different from what WebDriverWait normally handles (it handles during the waits just `NoSuchElementException`, by default). If that's the case, you have to pass those additional exceptions to its constructor:

```
WebDriverWait(self.your_webelemt_object, 20, ignored_exceptions=[NoSuchElementException, the_other_exceptions]).  # the rest omitted for brevity
```

Comment: Perfect, I was hesitant to try and bypass the default use case but this is a logical approach which seems safe. It's a shame they don't support these types of operations directly on the WebDriver elements. Thanks!